# Connect to Gtk::Window signal_delete_event

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm

I want to connect a signal to window.signal_delete_event, but it fails with the following error messages:

- no match for call to ‘(sigc::bound_mem_functor0) (_GdkEventAny* const&)’ OpticalInput
- return-statement with a value, in function returning 'void' [-fpermissive]
- void value not ignored as it ought to be

That is the code line causing the error:

```
window.signal_delete_event().connect(sigc::mem_fun(this,&GUIWindow::onExitClicked));
```

The pointed member function is this one:

```
void GUIWindow::onExitClicked()
{
    *state = false;
    Gtk::Main::quit();
}
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your method must match the signature of the signal. In the gtkmm documentation for `signal_delete_event()`, the following prototype is given:

```
bool on_my_delete_event(GdkEventAny* event)
```

Using your naming, the method must be defined as follows:

```
bool GUIWindow::onExitClicked(GdkEventAny* event) { ... }
```

The return value is used to indicate whether or not you have completely handled the event.  If you return true, other handlers for this event will not see it.